# css navbar position without fixed content position

Tags: html, css

the thing I couldn't solve is that when I set the navbar position fixed, it goes under "content-wrapper". Of course I can solve this problem if I give the content-wrapper "margin-top" but how can I solve this without using margin anywhere I want?

To summarize, I fix the "navbar-fixed" class both as static and with the help of a button, but when I want the navbar to remain constant, I want the "content" navbar to follow.

Thank you from now.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.container .side-menu {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    position: sticky;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 260px;
    top: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    z-index: 51000;
}
.container .content-area {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar-content {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-wrapper {
    background-repeat-x: repeat;
    z-index: 41001;
    width: 100%;
    height: 103px;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    top: 0;
}
.navbar-fixed .navbar-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    background: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1201px){
.container .navbar-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
}
}
.navbar--main {
    clear: both;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-skeleton {
    padding: .8rem 2.2rem;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
.navbar-skeleton {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.content-wrapper {
    padding: 1.3rem 2.2rem 2.2rem;
}
.footer-padding {
    padding: 1rem 2.2rem;
}
.footer-fixed footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 -4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container navbar-fixed footer-fixed">
    <div class="side-menu">menu
    </div>
    <div class="content-area">
        <div class="navbar-content">
            <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                <header class="navbar--main navbar-skeleton" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">navbar</header>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="router-view">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias asperiores consequatur corporis dolor dolorem eius eveniet expedita itaque magni minus natus neque, optio, perspiciatis quam, quod saepe soluta tempore temporibus!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, sunt, voluptatum. Ab accusamus adipisci aperiam blanditiis, dicta dolor doloremque, ducimus ipsam libero, minima molestiae nam nesciunt odit possimus vero? Ex.
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer-padding">COPYRIGHT ©2020 Pixinvent, All rights Reserved</footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could either use `position: sticky` or `css-grid` to accomplish your design without the need to use relative and absolute position and having the issues you facing in the first place.

Comment: If I understand your question, easiest thing to do is change ```.content-wrapper{ 4.3rem 2.2rem 2.2rem }```. You have to push it down one way or another, using ```margin: 3rem```, or ```position: relative; top: 25px;```, or ```transform: translateY(2rem)```.

Comment: @tacoshy I do not understand how to do?

Comment: @bjorn-b Can't be done without margin and ball?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following:

```
.navbar-content {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.footer-fixed footer {
    margin-top: auto;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

and you can get rid of `position:fixed`

Full code

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.container .side-menu {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    position: sticky;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 260px;
    top: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    z-index: 51000;
}
.container .content-area {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar-content {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}


@media (min-width: 1201px){
.container .navbar-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
}
}
.navbar--main {
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-skeleton {
    padding: .8rem 2.2rem;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
.navbar-skeleton {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.content-wrapper {
    padding: 1.3rem 2.2rem 2.2rem;
}
.footer-padding {
    padding: 1rem 2.2rem;
}
.footer-fixed footer {
    margin-top: auto;
    position: sticky;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 -4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container navbar-fixed footer-fixed">
    <div class="side-menu">menu
    </div>
    <div class="content-area">
        <div class="navbar-content">
            <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                <header class="navbar--main navbar-skeleton" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">navbar</header>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="router-view">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias asperiores consequatur corporis dolor dolorem eius eveniet expedita itaque magni minus natus neque, optio, perspiciatis quam, quod saepe soluta tempore temporibus!
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, sunt, voluptatum. Ab accusamus adipisci aperiam blanditiis, dicta dolor doloremque, ducimus ipsam libero, minima molestiae nam nesciunt odit possimus vero? Ex.
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer-padding">COPYRIGHT ©2020 Pixinvent, All rights Reserved</footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```